# How to check specific column have specific values or not in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I want to check that, if column 'data' is contains abc and xyz only or not. If not then return the same.
Expected output: False

```
 import pandas as pd
    data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42],'data':['abc','xyz','pqr','abc']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print df
```

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input.

Comment: Hi Mayank, here expected output is False as it also contains pqr also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test sets if want test if exist only some values in any order:

```
print (set(df['data']) == set(['xyz', 'abc']))
False
```

EDIT:

If need `True` if match at least one value:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42],
        'data':['abc','abc','abc','abc']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
    Name  Age data
0    Tom   28  abc
1   Jack   34  abc
2  Steve   29  abc
3  Ricky   42  abc

print (set(df['data']) <= set(['xyz', 'abc']))
True
```

Comment: what if `df['data']` contains only `'abc'`? +1 on `set` though.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Thank you, if OP need `True` is necessary test `<=` I think

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe :

```
 data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],
         'Age':[28,34,29,42],
         'data':['abc','xyz','pqr','abcd']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Try this one :

```
df[df['data'].isin(['abc','xyz'])]
```

there will be only 2 row as the result : Tom and Jack